# ¿Como eliminar vocales de una cadena en Ruby?

Tags: ruby

Tengo el siguiente array:

```
nombres = ["Violeta", "Andino", "Clemente", "Javiera", "Paula", "Pia", "Ray"]
a = nombres.map
```

Y quisiera crear otro y almacenarlo en la variable eliminando todas las vocales de los nombres.

Utilizando `.map` y `.gsub`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usted podría simplemente usar algo como esto:

```
string.gsub(/[aeiou]/, '')
```

O mejor:

```
string.tr('aeiou', '')
```

Y la mejor herramienta para eliminar caracteres en una cadena es ...

```
string.delete('aeiou')
```

Como sugiere @Gerry puede hacerlo así con `map`:

```
a = nombres.map { |nombre| nombre.delete('aeiou') }
```

> Fuente SO: [Ruby code for deleting the vowels in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34957102/8933039)

Aquí hay un Post que contiene una solución bastante amplia con varios ejemplos:

> - [Removing vowels from string in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37198175/8933039)

Comment: El código completo para responder a la pregunta sería: `a = nombres.map { |nombre| nombre.delete('aeiou') }`

Comment: @Gerry voy a copiar su sugerencia y agregarla a la respuesta si no le molesta.

Comment: Adelante, la intención del comentario era justamente esa: complementar la pregunta.